# Is $f(x)$ Riemann integrable?

Tags: calculus, riemann-integration

$$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{11}  x &       \mbox{when $x$ is rational} \\
             (-x) & \mbox{when $x$ is irrational} \end{array} \right. $$

Prove that $f(x)$ is not integrable over $[a, b]$

I thought along the line of finding an epsilon $\epsilon$ such that $ U(P, f) - L(P, f) >\epsilon$ but cannot proceed. Need help 
Thanks in advance

Comment: "\mbox" is useful for including English text within your maths displays. I've done the edit for you.

Comment: Thank you! I am new here and will learn

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$M_i=\sup_{[x_i,x_{i+1}]}f=-\inf_{[x_i,x_{i+1}]}=m_i$$

where $(x_i)$ is a partage $ P $ of $[a,b]$ .

$$U(P,f)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}M_i(x_{i+1}-x_i)=-L(P,f)=-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}m_i(x_{i+1}-x_i)$$

Comment: How is sup f equal to - inf f?

Comment: @user3137586 $f(x \notin Q)= - f(x\in Q)$.